# Based on the JSON provided, how to model Cassandra tables

Tags: cassandra

I have a json which is as follows:

```
{
"source": "source1",
"destination": [
    {
    "type":"DS",
    "zone":"DSZONE",
    "key_mapping":{
        "key1_source1":"key1_destination1",
        "key2_source2":"key2_destination2"
        }
    },
    .
    .
    .
],
```

}

Based on the above model, what is the best approach to create tables in Cassandra DB.

Comment: We do query based data modelling in cassandra. Please list down what all queries your application need to support ?  For example : get data for a given source.  A good blog for basic cassandra data modelling rules https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling

Comment: Hi Laxmikanth, Thanks for your reponse.

Comment: Query example: 1) Get Key1_destination1 from destination.

Comment: 2) Based on source, get destination with all its key_mapping